# ngFor items per row

Tags: angular, typescript, ngfor

I am struggling with display my data with *ngFor loop.
I want ngFor to display data 3 items per row. i tried with indexing. but then it was 1 item/row.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="mb-3 card-deck text-center">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow" *ngFor="let product of item.product;">
        <div class="card-header">
            <h4 class="my-0 font-weight-normal">{{ product.name }}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
                <img src="{{ product.imagePath}}" class="img-thumbnail" alt="{{ product.name }}"> 
                <p class="lead">{{ product.msg }} {{ product.msg2 }}</p>
                <a role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-primary" routerLink="product-details">More...</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I will highly appreciate any help. I am using

```
Angular-cli version 6.1.0
bootstrap 4
```

Comment: Btw, I guess here is a typo: `<div class="card-boy">` => `<div class="card-body">`

Comment: I edited it. Any help on the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use bootstrap css classes to display 3 items per row

Make similar structure to your html file

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 col-lg-4" *ngFor="let product of item.products">
  {{product.name}} | {{product.imagePath}} | {{product.msg2}} <!-- display product data -->
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what to do for 4  items per row ? @SarthakAggarwal can you please help I want to devide 4 image per row with it's description

Answer (score 9):

You can simply put logic on `index` as below :

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index">
  <div *ngIf="i % 3 == 0" class="row">
    {{ item }}
    <div *ngIf="i + 1 < items.length">{{ items[i + 1] }}</div>
    <div *ngIf="i + 2 < items.length">{{ items[i + 2] }}</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @mfarhan, please let me know if it helps you .

Comment: Thanks Harunur. But i think css solution below is more I'll use.